# How to tune MariaDB/MySQL in a docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I understand that it's easy to get a MariaDB docker container up and running, and using `nsenter` to edit config files is possible. But how can I tune the config files in this container, e.g. [the official MariaDB image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/), in a docker way? That is, the config would not be lost after upgrading the container, or affected by most container operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the container as

```
docker run -d -v /path/to/my/config:/etc/mysql
```

The config files would be on the host.